# Stored Procedure through error during OUTPUT Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetActiveServerURL
(
@ActiveURL VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @ActiveURL = RedirectURL FROM HealthCheck WHERE IsPrimary=1 AND Status=1
END
```

Error Message :
Procedure or function 'GetActiveServerURL' expects parameter '@ActiveURL', which was not supplied.

---

As I have declared ActiveURL as output parameter stil it expects as input

Comment: EXEC GetActiveServerURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT

Comment: It should be something like `DECLARE @ActiveURL VARCHAR(100); EXEC GetActiveServerURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT ;`

Answer (score 1):

You must mention in your call that the parameter is output also.

```
DECLARE @ActiveURL VARCHAR(100)
EXEC GetActiveServerURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT
```

Here how to execute `SP` from `C#`

```
string activeURL;

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = new SqlCommand())
{
   command.Connection = conn;
   command.CommandText = "GetActiveServerURL";
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ActiveURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
   param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
   command.Parameters.Add(param);
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   activeURL = param.Value;
}
```

Comment: When I call as EXEC GetActiveServerURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT.. again it is saying that : Must declare the scalar variable "@ActiveURL".

Comment: Do you see the first line in my post? Show more code.How you call the SP?

Comment: yeah I have seen it. Now How Call That procedure fron c#. Do I need to simply say cmd.CommandText = "GetActiveServerURL"; or anything else

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the procedure with a parameter and include the OUTPUT directive.

```
SET @ActiveURL = 'http://'

EXEC GetActiveServerURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetActiveServerURL
(
 DECLARE @ActiveURL VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @ActiveURL = RedirectURL FROM HealthCheck WHERE IsPrimary=1 AND Status=1
END  

EXEC GetActiveURL @ActiveURL OUTPUT



      Error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetActiveServerURL, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetActiveServerURL, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@ActiveURL"